# Combine Results in Same Column to get Average

Tags: postgresql

Lets say I have a table that looks like the following:

| Average Score | Team | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | New York Team | May |
| 3 | San Fran Team | May |
| 2 | Chi Team | May |
| 3 | Texas Team | May |
| 2 | New York Team | June |
| 3 | San Fran Team | June |
| 2 | Chi Team | June |
| 3 | Texas Team | June |

I want to get the average for certain combinations of teams. How would I get the average of New York Team + San Fran team in May, and the average for the Chi team + Texas team?

Basically I want New York + San Fran to = Tier 1 (average)
and Chi + Texas to = Tier 2 (average)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a with clause and get so the average from every team per month and then simply add the data as you see fit

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sportstable
>     ("Average Score" int, "Team" varchar(13), "Month" varchar(4))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO sportstable
>     ("Average Score", "Team", "Month")
> VALUES
>     (2, 'New York Team', 'May'),
>     (3, 'San Fran Team', 'May'),
>     (2, 'Chi Team', 'May'),
>     (3, 'Texas Team', 'May'),
>     (2, 'New York Team', 'June'),
>     (3, 'San Fran Team', 'June'),
>     (2, 'Chi Team', 'June'),
>     (3, 'Texas Team', 'June')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> 8 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> WITH average_month AS (SELECT "Month",
> MAX(CASE WHEN "Team" = 'New York Team' THEN "Average Score"
>             ELSE 0
>        END) AS "New York Team",
>        MAX(CASE WHEN "Team" = 'San Fran Team' THEN "Average Score"
>             ELSE 0
>        END) AS "San Fran Team",
>        MAX(CASE WHEN "Team" = 'Chi Team' THEN "Average Score"
>             ELSE 0
>        END) AS "Chi Team",
>        MAX(CASE WHEN "Team" = 'Texas Team' THEN "Average Score"
>             ELSE 0
>        END) AS "Texas Team"
> FROM 
>    sportstable
> GROUP BY "Month")
> SELECT 
>     "Month"
>     ,("New York Team" + "San Fran Team" ) AS Tier1
>     ,("Chi Team" + "Texas Team") AS Tier2
> FROM
>     average_month
> ```
>
> ```
> Month | tier1 | tier2
> :---- | ----: | ----:
> May   |     5 |     5
> June  |     5 |     5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4381978d93567a47629cfcca19b2ad99)*